# How to use delta function as initial data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, ricci-flow

Picture below is from 74th page of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. The (6.4.8) is
$$
-\partial_t u -\Delta u + Ru =0
\tag{6.4.8}
$$
where $R$ is scalar curvature. And the $N$ is
$$
N= -\int_M u \ln u dV
$$
where $M$ is closed manifold.

I want to show $\tilde N \rightarrow 0$. But I don't know how to solute (6.4.8) from $u(T)$ is a delta function (I know what is backward solution). In fact, I feel it can't be solved by analytic solution since $M$ is not especial.

> [image]